# BizTalk Server 2013 R2 Integration with Cloud API Last.fm

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I deployed "last.fm.client.solution" solution and reference blog post explaining about solution in [BizTalk Server 2013 R2 Integration with Cloud API Last.fm](https://blog.steef-jan-wiggers.com/2015/01/biztalk-server-2013-r2-integration-with-cloud-api-last-fm/) and having issue when retrying the information about TopAlbums base on artist name.

[image: client application event 1 -- getinfo about artist name]

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'GetTopAlbums'.

[image: client application event 2 -- TopAlbums base on artist name]

Send port "sp_last_fm_get_topalbums" configuration:

[image: sp_last_fm_get_topalbums]

[image: sp_last_fm_get_topalbums1]

[image: sp_last_fm_get_topalbums2]

[image: sp_last_fm_get_topalbums_messages tab]

Using postman to send RESTful request on “www.last.fm” as below and getting response back in form of XML:

```
https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&artist=Metallica&api_key=cb3ed1de60c3b1cddd346d199e1f4a80
```

Trying to understand why unhandled exception occurs during "TopAlbums" event ? (need help)

Reference and project solution file for deployment:

```
https://www.last.fm/api/show/artist.getTopAlbums

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/BizTalk-Server-2013-R2-191cb9ba/sourcecode?fileId=134181&pathId=1593570775
```

When using XML receive pipeline on send port "sp_last_fm_get_topalbums" I got below error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Microsoft BizTalk Server Negative Acknowledgment An error occurred while processing the message, refer to the details section for more information http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0{94CB475A-EE25-4D40-9A0A-4D66FEAC4525}0xc0c016ab0There was a failure executing the response(receive) pipeline: "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "XML disassembler" Send Port: "sp_last_fm_get_topalbums" URI: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0" Reason: Finding the document specification by message type "lfm" failed. Verify the schema deployed properly.

Comment: Are you setting any headers in the Messages tab?

Comment: Yes I used “GET” operation...I just update question.

Comment: Included project solution link for anyone interested to deploy solutions to understand how BT support cloud api..thanks

Comment: If you remove the XMLReceive (use a PassThru) and try again, is there a suspended message? Can you see what the contents of that message is from the BizTalk Admin Console?

Comment: That last error is telling you that it can't find a schema deployed in BizTalk that matches the xml.  It looks like your message doesn't have any namespace (as it would show up in the error usually) so it is looking for a schema with the root node "lfm" but can't find that either.

Comment: exactly GetTopAlbums response messages schema only have root name as lfm and doen't include name space on it .so, I doubt on endpoint that might be not working though I got response back from postman for GetTopAlbums..... And I have something like An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'GetTopAlbums'. as an error messages.

Comment: After enable tracking on send port it’s look like BT getting response back from “lastfm” REST endpoint (to large message I can’t paste it here ) using group hub completed instances tab and something went wrong on storing response messages value on windows asp.net form application what I’m trying to display (need redesign .net application to get there) other then that everything look perfect...thanks for help and it’s excellent project !!!